# Feed importer different node from each element

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

i am having some issues with feed importer. I am trying to create two different nodes from a JSON with feed importer. For example i have the following JSON and i need to create a "HOME" titled node and an "IPHONE" titled node, and each one of these should have the right number. The question to simplify this, is how to have them in different nodes. Thanks in advance!

```
{
 "firstName": "John",
 "lastName" : "doe",
 "age"      : 26,
 "address"  :
 {
     "streetAddress": "naist street",
     "city"         : "Nara",
     "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
 },
 "phoneNumbers":
 [
     {
       "type"  : "iPhone",
       "number": "0123-4567-8888"
     },
     {
       "type"  : "home",
       "number": "0123-4567-8910"
     }
 ]
```

}